# How to set up Skype 5.4.0.1 to recognize my Omega ouv175 webcam on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: skype, webcam

I tested my webcam with Cheese and VLC and it works, but Skype won't recognize it. So, what do I need to configure to use my webcam (video and microphone features)?

`lsusb` output:

[image: lsusb]

Comment: For starters, if it is a USB my webcam, you can add the output of `lsusb` to the question. In other words, open a terminal window, type `lsusb` and hit Enter.

Comment: lsusb output: https://prnt.sc/g79e4r

Answer (score 1):

Since Microsoft has chosen to strip down Skype to its less than bare essentials, all of the customization preferences have disappeared, and if it doesn't see your camera, there's currently nothing that can be done about it, except hope that a future version will work for you.

**Update #1:**

You might try...

1. plugging the camera directly into a computer USB port (not via a hub or extender)
2. try using a different computer USB port